# app with magick++ returns Magick++/Functions.h:14:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found

Tags: c++, macos, imagemagick

I'm trying to build a simple C++ app in MacOS (Big Sur) using ImageMagick

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.7)
project(HelloWorld)
add_definitions(-std=c++17)

set(CXX_FLAGS "-Wall")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS, "${CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(HelloWorld src/main.cpp)

add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_QUANTUM_DEPTH=16 )
add_definitions( -DMAGICKCORE_HDRI_ENABLE=0 )
find_package(ImageMagick COMPONENTS Magick++)
include_directories(${ImageMagick_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(HelloWorld ${ImageMagick_LIBRARIES})
```

and on my main.cpp, I just have `#include <Magick++.h>` at the top of the file

When I run the build I get the

`/usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/7.0.10-48/include/ImageMagick-7/Magick++/Functions.h:14:10: fatal error: 'string' file not found`

any ideas what's the issue here? I reinstalled imagemagick but I still get the same error.

CMake version is 3.19

EDIT:

Seems that the issue is with my macOS setup, I tried just compiling a simple hello world, and I get the same error with
`#include <iostream>`

Any idea on how to fix/reset the c++/gcc setup on mac?

Comment: I think I read somewhere that the compiler on macOS no longer looks in the *"standard"* locations, so you may have to use `g++ -I /usr/include ...` or somesuch.

Comment: How can I do that with cmake?

Answer (score 1):

I presume that you used **homebrew** to install your **GCC**, i.e. *"GNU Compiler Collection"* which includes `g++` the C++ compiler. So, in order to get the version number, you can run:

```
ls /usr/local/bin/g++*
```

**Sample Output**

```
/usr/local/bin/g++-10
```

Now you need to tell `cmake` to use that compiler, so you would use:

```
CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++-10 cmake ..
```